# What is the q @ symbol doing in the context of being applied as a function call?

Tags: kdb, q-lang

What is going on in the example here?

Source: http://code.kx.com/q/ref/select/#index-at

```
@[d;1 1 1;+;3]
((1 2 3;4 5 6 7);(17 18;19;20 21);(13 14;15 16 17 18;19 20))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://code.kx.com/wiki/JB:QforMortals2/functions#Functional_Forms_of_Amend

> @[L;I;f;y]
>   L=your list
>   I=index of elements to modify
>   f=function to apply
>   y=2nd parameter to f

You can see what it is doing by placing `+` in a function and adding some logging output. In this case it indexes into the 2nd element `d@1`, retrieves `(8 9;10;11 12)`, adds 3, results in `(11 12;13;14 15)`, uses that as it's next input, adds 3, results in `(14 15;16;17 18)`.

```
    q)@[d;1 1 1;{0N!("x is:",.Q.s1 x;"y is:",.Q.s1 y);x+y};3]
    ("x is:(8 9;10;11 12)";"y is:3")
    ("x is:(11 12;13;14 15)";"y is:3")
    ("x is:(14 15;16;17 18)";"y is:3")
    (1 2 3;4 5 6 7)
    (17 18;19;20 21)
    (13 14;15 16 17 18;19 20)
```

Or it can be seen using over(`/`):

```
    q)@/[d;;{0N!(x;y);x+y};3]1 1 1
    ((8 9;10;11 12);3)
    ((11 12;13;14 15);3)
    ((14 15;16;17 18);3)
    (1 2 3;4 5 6 7)
    (17 18;19;20 21)
    (13 14;15 16 17 18;19 20)
```